# Print PHP JSON encoded array, to JavaScript and decode it, produces errors

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have to use some data from PHP to JavaScript. I am using JSON for that. I encode the array with PHP's `json_encode` function and then I want to decode it with JavaScript.

```
<?php
$data = array(
"..."=>"...",
.....
);
?>

<script>
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>');
console.log(data);
</script>
```

The problem is sometimes produces errors in javascript console on parsing the JSON, most of times when `$data` contains HTML.

How can I print a json encoded code inside javascript, dinamically with PHP?

Thank you!

Comment: `var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;`

Answer (score 4):

JSON is in fact JavaScript Object Notation, it can be echoed directly in a variable, and doesn't need parsing.

```
var data = <?= json_encode($data); ?>;
```

Answer (score 2):

The errors will typically come from when the data contains `'` (which prematurely terminate your string literal) or new line characters (which get parsed by the JS parser and render the JSON invalid).

You could get around this by explicitly escaping such characters (with a string replacement function run on the generated JSON), but that is more effort than is worth going to.

Since JSON is a subset of the JavaScript literal syntax, you can just treat it as JavaScript directly. You don't need to wrap it in a string and then parse that string to the JS data structure.

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
```